# Pass Data back to parentView: isMovingToParentViewController not working?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, parent-child

I implemented a navigation controller in my iPad app which works perfectly fine.

Now, on one view of the navigation stack I want to pass data to the parent view if popped to it.

I tried this in the child view controller:

(property of dataArray +synthesize in both views)

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

if([self isMovingToParentViewController])
{
int currentVCIndex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self.navigationController.topViewController];

ParentViewController *parent = (ParentViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentVCIndex];

parent.dataArray = self.dataArray;
}


}
```

Any Ideas why not working?

Comment: why not holding a permanent reference to the parent view? Otherwise I recomand a protocol methode for a "callback" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584930/objective-c-accessing-methods-from-custom-cell/16585079#16585079

Answer (score 0):

It is working when using `isMovingFromParentViewController` instead of `isMovingToParentViewController`.

That doesn't make any sense to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It seems isMoving has nothing to do with the navigation stack at all. Even when using `[self.navigationController isMovingToParentVC]`, it's only saying that it's moving, to whatever view.